# Powershell Test-Path on FTP not working properly in IF condition

Tags: powershell

I am ruining my brain over this "Test-Path" condition. Help would be really appreciated. Here is what I want to do :

1. Open a session to a distant FTP in the folder /OUT/
2. List every ".csv" files in this /OUT/ folder
3. Copy them to \myshare
4. List every ".csv" files that have been copied to \myshare
5. Log all the activity
6. Close the connection

These are all the steps and if there are no ".csv" files in the FTP, it HAS TO log that the files had already been copied to the share.

I removed the comments that are logged because it is in French. If required, I can repost the complete code. The comments are just "echo "some blabla" >> $log

Anyway...
Whatever I do, the code is going through the "IF" condition and it is ALWAYS TRUE ! Even if there are no ".csv" files in the /OUT/ folder on the FTP 
The script is never going through the "ELSE" part.

I would really appreciate some help, because I'm getting mad at this, as I don't understand what is going wrong

I am pretty sure that it is something very obvious that I cannot see.

Here is the code :

```
    $date = Get-Date
    $datef = Get-Date -format yyyy_MM_dd@HH-mm-ss
    $distant = "/OUT/"
    $checkdistant = Test-Path -Path $distant | Where-Object { (-not $_.IsDirectory) -and ($_.Name -ne "*.csv")}
    $localfile = "\\myshare\*.csv"
    $log = New-Item -Path c:\Logs\ -ItemType file -Name Log_Out$($datef).txt

    Add-Type -Path "C:\scripts\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
        Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
        HostName = ""
        UserName = ""
        Password = ""
        SshHostKeyFingerprint = ""
    }

    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
    $session.SessionLogPath = "c:\Logs\$(((get-date).ToLocalTime()).ToString("yyyy_MM_dd@HH-mm-ss"))_FTP_Session.log"
    $sessionftp = $session.SessionLogPath
    try
    {
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)
    $dir = $session.ListDirectory($distant)
    foreach ($fileInfo in $dir.Files)
    { 
    $remotedir = ($fileInfo.FullName + " " + " " + $fileInfo.LastWriteTime)
    $remotedir >> $log
    } 
    if ($checkdistant = $true)
    { 
    $session.GetFiles("/OUT/*", "\\myshare\").Check 
    $ls = ls $localfile 
    $ls >> $log
echo "$date "files copied OK to \\myshere" >> $log
    $session.RemoveFiles( 'OUT/*.csv' )
    } 
    else 
    { 
    echo "`r$date my blabla to my log" >> $log
    }
    } 
    finally
    {
    $session.Dispose()
    exit 0
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

## 1. `=` instead of `-eq`

This is a classic/common PowerShell mistake.

```
If ($checkdistant = $true) { }
```

Is both setting `$checkdistant` to true and then evaluating if it's true (which it always is). You need to do:

```
If ($checkdistant -eq $true) { }
```

You could also just do:

```
If ($checkdistant) { }
```

As it's true by virtue of having any value.

## 2. Test-Path returns a true/false result not a list of file objects

This isn't working quite as you imagine:

```
$checkdistant = Test-Path -Path $distant | Where-Object { (-not $_.IsDirectory) -and ($_.Name -ne "*.csv")}
```

Because `Test-Path` returns a true/false result, which you are then passing to Where-Object to filter on whether it's not a directory and not a file with the extension .csv.

You probably want to do this instead:

```
$distant = (Get-ChildItem -Path "/OUT/" | Where-Object { (-not $_.IsDirectory) -and ($_.Name -ne "*.csv")}).FullName
$checkdistant = Test-Path -Path $distant
```

This uses `Get-ChildItem` to get the `.FullName` property of a the files that match your filter and then you use that list with `Test-Path`.

I think you could actually simplify this further by doing:

```
$distant = (Get-ChildItem -Path "/OUT/" -Directory -Exclude *.csv).FullName
```